# autocomplete dropdown in Infragistics ultrawebgrid cell

Tags: autocomplete, drop-down-menu, infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I want to an autocomplete dropdown control in the ultrawebgrid cell in edit mode, so user can type the data and value is filled in automatically if exists, invalid data should not be permitted. is this possible? I don't want to use webcombo, it is too heavy and I don't need a multi-column dropdown. I want a simple dropdownlist, but the ability for the user to type just like Google suggest, but all the values cached on the client, no roundtrip to server on each key stroke.

the control should be like the following one

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

thanks,

RK

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to accomplish something like what you want. Here is what I did, but I don't know if it works into the Infragistics package:

1- I downloaded the JQuery UI autofill textbox
2- I modified a little bit the sample given on the site.
3- I applied something to modify all my dropdown having a class named XYZ for the auto complete. I used a delegate, so when it generate a dropdown on the UI, it replaces it automatically by my autofill textbox.

Sorry if my english is not perfect, it is not my first language.

here's some code (Note: In the sample I haven't used the live() or delegate() function):

```
(function($) {
    $.widget("ui.autoCompleteDDL", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this;
            var select = this.element.hide();
            var _isHoverUl = false;

            var input = $("<input>")
                .addClass("ig_Edit igtxt_Edit")
                .width(select.width())
                .addClass(select.attr("class"))
                .removeClass("AutoComplete DropDownList")
                .click(function(e){this.select(); })
                .insertAfter(select)
                .autocomplete({
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp(request.term, "i");
                        response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                            var text = $(this).text();
                            if (!request.term || matcher.test(text))
                                return {
                                    id: $(this).val(),
                                    label: text.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + request.term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                    value: text
                                };
                        }));
                    },
                    delay: 100,
                    select: function(e, ui) {
                        if (!ui.item) {
                            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                            $(this).val("");
                            return false;
                        }
                        $(this).focus();
                        select.val(ui.item.id);

                        self._trigger("selected", null, {
                            item: select.find("[value='" + ui.item.id + "']")
                        });

                    },
                    minLength: 1
                })
                .blur(function(e){
                        var curInput= $(this);
                        if (!_isHoverUl){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                curInput.val(select.get(0).options[select.get(0).selectedIndex].text);
                                input.autocomplete("close");
                            }, 150); // 150 is because of the autocomplete implementation.
                        }
                    });

            // Fix for the scrollbar in IE7/8
            $("body")
                .delegate(".ui-autocomplete", "mouseover", function(evt){ _isHoverUl = true;})
                .delegate(".ui-autocomplete", "mousemove", function(evt){input.focus();})
                .delegate(".ui-autocomplete", "mouseout", function(evt){_isHoverUl = false;});

            // Possibility of showing an arrow button.
            $("<div>&nbsp;</div>")
            .insertAfter(input)
            .addClass("ui-icon-combo-arrow")
            .mouseover(function(){$(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-combo-arrow ui-icon-combo-arrowH"); })
            .mouseout(function(){$(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-combo-arrow ui-icon-combo-arrowH"); })
            .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
            .css({"display":"inline"})
            .position({
                my: "left center",
                at: "right center",
                of: input,
                offset: "-1 0"
            })
            .attr("title", "")
            .click(function() {
                // close if already visible
                if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                    input.autocomplete("close");
                    return;
                }
                // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete("search", "");
                input.focus();
            });

            input.val(select.get(0).options[select.get(0).selectedIndex].text);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $("select.AutoComplete").autoCompleteDDL();
});
```

I hope this helped